# How does three of a kind beat a full house?

Tags: hand

Okay, this is my first day of Poker and I'm confused.

[image]

Doesn't one player have 77799 which is a full house? And other player have three of kings? Caster says at one point Hellmuth needed to hit quads to win (he meant 7 quads?), but isn't that a full house anyway? Isn't that higher hand than three of a kind, I'm lost here.

Full video https://youtu.be/siygBUw-Uug?t=125

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hellmuth has 777KK.  Minieri has KKK77.  Since the strength of full houses are determined by the three of a kind, Minieri has the winning hand.

Remember that in Texas Hold'em, you are allowed to use anywhere from none to both of your hole cards to make the best hand.

Comment: Oh I'm just blind.